# How can I get this Summary To Work?

Tags: python

I'm trying my hand at making a character generator (python 2.7) for a pen and paper game I wrote. I've been working on this thing all day without a hitch until i hit the very end of the code. Right now its broken, I cant figure out a way to get it to print a character sheet at the end. Keep in mind im a total newbie and using a bunch of stuff here where i'm just experimenting. If anyone can help me get the end to work and print a character sheet using all the info generated before hand in the code, i would really appreciate it! What i think is going wrong is that i need a way for the code to ignore a variable if its skipped over in the ID generator. Anyway, here is the code.

```
##########################################################
# Cyberpanky N.O.W Python Character Generator by Ray Weiss
#
# Created 9/24/2012
#
# Much thanks to Connor Daliposon 
# Mho made a very readable D&D Character Generator  
# That a Python newbie like me could understand                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
##########################################################

# Imports
import random
from pprint import pprint


# Hey there
print """
Hello world & welcome to the CYBERPANKY N.O.W. character generator.
Programmed by Ray Weiss. 
To quit at anytime, press CNTRL-C.
"""

print "Lets figure out your stats first. Press enter to continue."
raw_input()

# Stat Roller
# Rolls 3D6 and adds the sum together and prints

def roll_stats():
    a = random.randint(1, 6)
    b = random.randint(1, 6) 
    c = random.randint(1, 6)
    d = random.randint(1, 6)
    list = [a, b, c, d]
    list.sort()
    add = sum(list[1:4])
    return add

# Modifiers

def pow_mod():
    a = "|+1 to hit on mele attack rolls| "
    b = "|+1 damage on mele attack rolls|"

    if pow >= 15 and pow < 17:
        return a
    if pow >= 17:
        return a + b
    else: 
        return " ~no modifiers~"

def iq_mod():   
    a = "|-500$ to invest in cyberspace| "
    b = "|Reroll Street Doc abilities|"

    if iq >= 15 and iq < 17:
        return a
    if iq >= 17:
        return a + b
    else: 
        return " ~no modifiers~"

def agi_mod():
    a = "|+1 to hit with ranged weapons| "
    b = "|-1 to hit with ranged weapons|"

    if agi >= 12:
        return a
    if agi <= 9:
        return b
    else: 
        return " ~no modifiers~"

def con_mod():
    a = "|+1 hit point per hit dice|"
    b = "|-1 hit point per hit dice|"

    if con >= 15:
        return a
    elif con <= 6: 
        return b
    else: 
        return " ~no modifiers~"

def cyn_mod():
    a = "|Add 10% to earned experience|"
    b = "|Add 5% to earned experience|"
    c = "|Subtract 10% from earned experience|"
    d = "|Subtract 20% from earned experience|"

    if cyn >= 15:
        return a
    elif cyn > 12 and cyn < 15:
        return b
    elif cyn > 6 and cyn < 9:
        return c
    elif cyn <= 6:
        return d
    else: 
        return " ~no modifiers~"

def cha_mod():
    a = "|+1 to reaction rolls|"
    b = "|-1 to reaction rolls|"

    if cha >= 15:
        return a 
    if cha <= 8:
        return b
    else: 
        return " ~no modifiers~"

# Prints stats + modifiers.
pow = roll_stats()
print "Power:", pow, pow_mod()
iq = roll_stats()
print "Intelligence:", iq, iq_mod()
agi = roll_stats()
print "Agility:", agi, agi_mod()
con = roll_stats()
print "Constitution:", con, con_mod()
cyn = roll_stats()
print "Cynicism:", cyn, cyn_mod()
cha = roll_stats()
print "Charisma:", cha, cha_mod()

print "\nIf you dont like your stats, tough shit. This is Cyberpanky N.O.W."
print "\nPress enter to continue."
raw_input()

# Choose Class

print """In Cyberpanky N.O.W. there are only 3 character classes. 

1. Samurai: Badass mercenaries. Can make multiple attacks.  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2. Street Docs: Hackers / Doctors. Can heal & hack. 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3. Shaman: Magical prophets that follow spirit animals and cast miracles 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
type = int(raw_input("Please type a 1, 2, or 3 > "))

if type == 1:
    character_class = "Samurai"
    class_power = """* Attack multiple times for a -2 to hit penalty.
* Uses a D10 for Physical hit box.
* Has a + 1 to hit bonus that levels up to level 5. 
"""
    name = raw_input("Alright {}, tell me your name >".format(character_class))

elif type == 2:
    character_class = "Street Doc"
    class_power = """* Roll IQ to mess with electronics
* Can heal party members after combat for 1D4 Hit Points
* Can perform cyberwear installation or surgery with proper tools.
"""
    name = raw_input("Alright {}, tell me your name >".format(character_class))

elif type == 3:
    character_class = "Shaman"
    class_power = """* Can cast Miracles.
* Can call for a saving grace if they are on their last Cool Hit Box
* Can do favors for their god for more miracles, or pay a tithe.
"""
    name = raw_input("Alright {}, tell me your name >".format(character_class))

# Alignment

print"""\nAlright {}, pick an alignment, it's not that important;

1. Narcissist: Cocky bastard, you think you are the best.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2. Neutral: Pretty self explanatory dipshit. 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3. Nihilist: You care about nothing Lebowski, You'll cut off their Johnson. 
""".format(name)

x = int(raw_input("Please type a 1, 2, or 3 > "))

if x == 1:
    alignment = "Narcissist"

elif x == 2:
    alignment = "Neutral"

elif x == 3:
    alignment = "Nihilist"

print "\nOk you chose {} for an alignment, press enter to continue.".format(
                                                                alignment)
raw_input()

# Functions for ID generation

def gen_id():
    global gender_id
    one = "1. Straight male"
    two = "2. Gay male"
    three = "3. Transgender male pre-op"
    four = "4. Transgender male post-op"
    five = "5. Bisexual male"
    six = "6. Straight female"
    seven = "7. Gay female"
    eight = "8. Transgender female pre-op"
    nine = "9. Transgender female post-op"
    ten = "10. Bisexual female"
    list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
    pprint(list)
    print "\nPlease hit enter to roll 1D10"
    raw_input()
    gender_id = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(gender_id)
    raw_input()

# Ethnic Profile
def eth_pr():
    global ethnic_pr
    one = "1. Native American"
    two = "2. West European"
    three = "3. East European"
    four = "4. North Asian"
    five = "5. South Asian"
    six = "6. Pacific"
    seven = "7. North African"
    eight = "8. South African"
    nine = "9. Slavic / Caucuses"
    ten = "10. Hispanic"
    list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
    pprint(list)
    print "\nPlease hit enter to roll 1D10"
    raw_input()
    ethnic_pr = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(ethnic_pr)
    raw_input()

# Family Class Distinction
def fam_cls():
    global fcd
    one = "1. Homeless"
    two = "2. Impoverished"
    three = "3. Lower Class"
    four = "4. Lower Middle Class"
    five = "5. Middle Class"
    six = "6. Comfortable"
    seven = "7. Upper Middle Class"
    eight = "8. Upper Class"
    nine = "9. Job Creators"
    ten = "10. Warren Buffett"
    list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
    pprint(list)
    print "Please hit enter to roll 1D10"
    raw_input()
    fcd = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(fcd)
    raw_input()

# Whats Good With Your Folks
def wha_goo():
    global wg, one_x, two_x
    one_x = "1. Things Are Good With Your Folks; Go to Current Family Affairs"
    two_x = "2. Your folks are fucked; go to Your Folks Got Fucked"
    list = [one_x, two_x]
    pprint(list)
    print "Please hit enter to roll 1D2"
    raw_input()
    wg = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(wg)
    raw_input()

# Your Folks Got Fucked
def yo_fo():
    global fogo_fuck
    one = "1. Your parents were mugged and murdered, just like Batman"
    two = "2. Your parents were both convicted of murder"
    three = "3. Parents decapitated by a truck"
    four = "4. Parents addicted to coke, put you in an orphanage"
    five = "5. Parents were corporate spies and assinated in front of you"
    six = "6. Parents abandonded you at a young age and joined a cult"
    seven = "7. Your parents died from STDs contracted from aldultery"
    eight = "8. Parents owed mob a bunch of money, sleeping with fishies"
    nine = "9. Nuclear explosion incinerated parents, their shadow remains"
    ten = "10. Parents shot themselves immediately after you were born."
    list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
    pprint(list)
    print "Please hit enter to roll 1D10"
    raw_input()
    fogo_fuck = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(fogo_fuck)
    raw_input()

# Current Family Affairs
def cu_fa():
    global cur_fam, one_y, two_y
    one_y = "1. Things are ok with family, go to Nature Or Nurture"
    two_y = "2. Your family is fucked, go to Your Family Is Fucked"
    list = [one_y, two_y]
    pprint(list)
    print "Please hit enter to roll 1D2"
    raw_input()
    cur_fam = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(cur_fam)
    raw_input()

# Your Family Got Fucked
def fa_fu():
    global fam_fuk
    one = "1. Market tanked with president Paul, dead broke family."
    two = "2. Home invaders raped and murded the women in your family"
    three = "3. Racial Supremisicist drove your family from their home"
    four = "4. Whole family was abducted by aliens, never seen again"
    five = "5. Radiation leak hospitalized your whole family."
    six = "6. Family was accidentally napalmed by the UN, all dead."
    seven = "7. Family came down with malaria"
    eight = "8. Family has some obvious dealings with Illuminati"
    nine = "9. Family eaten alive by cannibals"
    ten = "10. Make it up dipshit"
    list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
    pprint(list)
    raw_input()
    fam_fuk = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(fam_fuk)
    raw_input()

# Nature Or Nurture
def na_nu():
    global nat_nur
    one = "1. Your childhood was very boring & average" 
    two = "2. Your childhood was spent moving from city to city"
    three = "3. Your childhood was depraved; hungry and lonely"
    four = "4. Your childhood was rewarding, social & fun."
    five = "5. You were a sick child, spent a lot of time in bed"
    six = "6. You were sent to a preppy boarding school as a kid"
    seven = "7. You got addicted to drugs; it screwed you up."
    eight = "8. You killed another kid, spent time in a hospital"
    nine = "9. You were a child genius, but had few friends"
    ten = "10. Make it up dipshit"
    list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
    pprint(list)
    print "Please hit enter to roll 1D10"
    raw_input()
    nat_nur = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(nat_nur)
    raw_input()

# General Disposition
def ge_di():
    global gen_dis
    one = "1. Friendly"
    two = "2. Unfriendly"
    three = "3. Shy"
    four = "4. Outgoing"
    five = "5. Unpretentious"
    six = "6. Pretentious"
    seven = "7. Hyperactive"
    eight = "8. Depressed"
    nine = "9. Wonderful Human Being"
    ten = "10. Scumbag"
    list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
    pprint(list)
    print "Please hit enter to roll 1D10"
    raw_input()
    gen_dis = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(gen_dis)
    raw_input()

# Whats the most important thing in the world
def wh_wo():
    global wha_wor
    one = "1. Money"
    two = "2. Kicking ass"
    three = "3. Getting fucked up"
    four = "4. Family & friends"
    five = "5. Business"
    six = "6. The internet" 
    seven = "7. Faith"
    eight = "8. Style"
    nine = "9. Anarchy"
    ten = "10. Selfishness"
    list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
    pprint(list)
    print "Please hit enter to roll 1D10"
    raw_input()
    wha_wor = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(wha_wor)
    raw_input()

# Who is to blame for the worlds problems?
def wh_pr():
    global who_pro
    one = "1. Corporations"
    two = "2. Leftists"
    three = "3. Fate"
    four = "4. Religion"
    five = "5. The Illuminatus"
    six = "6. The News Media"
    seven = "7. The UN"
    eight = "8. Your Neighbors"
    nine = "9. Aliens"
    ten = "10. President Ron Paul"
    list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
    pprint(list)
    print "Please hit enter to roll 1D10"
    raw_input()
    who_pro = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(who_pro)
    raw_input()

# How do you solve the worlds problems
def ho_pr():
    global how_pro
    one = "1. Kill them all"
    two = "2. But them out"
    three = "3. Intimidation"
    four = "4. Diplomacy"
    five = "5. Free trade"
    six = "6. Seduction"
    seven = "7. New-Age spirituality"
    eight = "8. Religious fanaticism"
    nine = "9. Federal power"
    ten = "10. Who gives a shit"
    list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
    pprint(list)
    print "Please hit enter to roll 1D10"
    raw_input()
    how_pro = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(how_pro)
    raw_input()


# ID Generation

print ("Alright {}, now we need to figure out your personality & life story."
                                                               .format(name))
print "\n\t\t1. Ethnics, Genes, & Looks"
print "\nTo figure out your age, we add 15 to 1D10.\n"
age = random.randint(1, 10) + 15
print "Press enter to continue dipshit."
raw_input()
print "Age:", age
print "\t\tGender Identity\n"
gen_id()
print "\t\tEthnic Profile\n"
eth_pr()
print "\t\t2. Ballz Of Our Fathers"
print "\n"
print "\t\tFamily Class Distinction"
fam_cls()
print "\t\tWhat's Good With Your Folks"
wha_goo()
if wg == one_x:
    fogo_fuck = "none"
    print "\t\tCurrent Family Affairs"
    cu_fa()
    print "\t\tNature Or Nurture?"
    na_nu()
    if cur_fam == one_y:
        fam_fuk = "none"
        print "\t\tNature Or Nurture?"
        na_nu()
    if cur_fam == two_y:
        print "\t\t Your Family Is Fucked"
        fa_fu()
if wg == two_x:
    print "\t\tYour Folks Got Fucked"
    yo_fo()
    print "\t\tCurrent Family Affairs"
    cu_fa()
    print "\t\tNature Or Nurture?"
    na_nu()
    if cur_fam == one_y:
        print "\t\tNature Or Nurture?"
        na_nu()
    if cur_fam == two_y:
        print "\t\t Your Family Is Fucked"
        fa_fu()
print "\t\t3. What Makes you tick"
print "\n"
print "\t\tGeneral Disposition"
ge_di()
print "\t\tWhat's The Most Important Thing In The World?"
wh_wo()
print "\t\tWho Is To Blame For The World's Problems?"
wh_pr()
print "\t\tHow Do You Solve Your / The Worlds Problem"
ho_pr()

#Starting Money
gold = roll_stats() * 100

print "Ok so lets sum that up, please hit enter to continue"
raw_input()

print"""
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""

# Character Sheet Function.
def char_shee():
    print "Name:", name
    print "Class:", character_class
    print "Class Powers:", class_power
    print "Alignment:", alignment
    print "Power:", pow, pow_mod()
    print "Intelligence:", iq, iq_mod()
    print "Agility:", agi, agi_mod()
    print "Constitution:", con, con_mod()
    print "Cynicism:", cyn, cyn_mod()
    print "Charisma:", cha, cha_mod()
    print "All Characters Start With 3 Hit Dice"
    print"""
\t\t{0}' History
\t\t------------------
\t\tAge:{1}
\t\t{2}
\t\t{3}
\t\t{4}
\t\t{5}
\t\t{6}
\t\t{7}
\t\t{8}
\t\t{9}
\t\t{10}
\t\t{11}
\t\t{12}
\t\t{13}
\t\t{14}
""".format(name, age, gender_id, ethnic_pr, fcd, wg, fogo_fuck, cur_fam,fam_fuk, nat_nur, gen_dis, wha_wor, who_pro, how_pro)

char_shee()
```

Let me know if i posted this in the wrong place, or if i need to pony up any more information, though i think ive finally posted this in the right place this time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an IndexError because you don't have enough positional arguments in the .format() statement on line 517. You should have 15, but you've only got 14.

If you remove the line 516:

```
    \t\t{14}
```

Everything will work fine.

Comment: I think i answered my own question, added a couple of lines saying fam_fuk = "none" when its not chosen, and it looks like its working now! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

use classes

```
class player(object):
      def __init__(self):
          self.pow = roll_stats()
          self.iq = roll_stats()
          self.agi = roll_stats()
          self.con = roll_stats()
          self.cyn = roll_stats()
          self.cha = roll_stats()
          self.special = ''
      def __str__(self):
          return """"
         Power:%s
         Intelligence:%s
         Agillity:%s
         Constitution:%s
         Cynasism:%s
         Charisma:%s
         %s
"""%(self.pow,self.iq,self.agi,self.com,self.syn,self.cha,self.special)
```

and just do

```
p = player()
print p
```

Comment: I had a feeling I could use classes to make things more similar, but i havent gotten up to classes in the book im learning with yet so i hadn't tried to use them, ill play around with this though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was not your question, but let me add a changed version of `roll_stats`.

```
return roll_stats():
    def d6():
        return random.randint(1, 6)

    return sum(sorted((d6(), d6(), d6(), d6()))[1:4])
```